# remotely boot into different kernel version

Tags: ubuntu, boot, remote, kernel

I have a **remote** machine with Ubuntu 12.04 and the following kernel **versions** installed:

```
:/lib/modules# ls
2.6.39.4  3.0.0-21-generic  3.2.0-25-generic  3.2.0-25-generic-pae  3.2.0-27-generic  3.2.0-27-generic-pae
```

I need to boot into version **2.6**. Can I do it remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could prove risky if something goes wrong but basically just change your grub (check */boot/grub/grub.cfg*) to include also that kernel version in the menu and put it as the default kernel (change the *set default="0"* to point to your 2.6 entry). And do a reboot and hope it comes back!

You could explore the "boot once" grub option to do just one boot in 2.6.x. Look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-once_002donly.html). But you may still need somebody to power cycle the PC if something goes very bad and the kernel gets stuck. But at least you may come back easily without the need of a rescue tool.